# Difference between HttpClient PostAsync and SendAsync

Tags: c#, wpf, async-await, dotnet-httpclient

Working on a project where a WPF front end, and trying to get a handle on async calls to `HttpClient` and I've been going around and around trying to get `PostAsync` to work, but it routinely appears to deadlock, or at least the post response times out, even with large values for timeout, and a visible response in fiddler.

So, after a while I decided to try out a few other methods on HttpClient, and they worked, first try. No idea why.

I'm clean all the way to my WPF button with `awaits`, `asyncs`, and `.ConfigureAwait(false)` (I think):

Button:

```
private async void Generate_Suite_BTN_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    await suiteBuilder.SendStarWs().ConfigureAwait(false);
}
```

XmlDoc Load:

```
internal async Task SendStarWs()
{
    var xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
    xmlDoc.Load("C:\\Temp\\file.xml");
    await StarWSClient.SendStarMessage(xmlDoc).ConfigureAwait(false);
}
```

SendMessage:

```
private static readonly HttpClient Client = new HttpClient {MaxResponseContentBufferSize = 1000000};

public static async Task<STARResult> SendMessage(vars)
{
var response = await SendRequestAsync(url, contentNew, Client).ConfigureAwait(false);
return new STARResult(response, hash);
}
```

This call '500s' against my endpoint immediately, which I'd expect:

```
var response = await SendRequestAsync(url, contentNew, Client).ConfigureAwait(false);

private static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendRequestAsync(string adaptiveUri, StringContent content, HttpClient httpClient)
{
    HttpResponseMessage responseMessage = null;
    try
    {
        responseMessage = await httpClient.SendAsync(new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, adaptiveUri)).ConfigureAwait(false);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        if (responseMessage == null)
            responseMessage = new HttpResponseMessage
            {
                StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError,
                ReasonPhrase = $"SendRequestAsync failed: {ex.Message}"
            };
    }
    return responseMessage;
}
```

The Post variant returns a TaskCancellationException, with timeout message regardless of timeout value:

```
var response = await PostRequestAsync(url, contentNew, Client).ConfigureAwait(false);

private static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> PostRequestAsync(string adaptiveUri, StringContent content, HttpClient httpClient)
{
    HttpResponseMessage responseMessage = null;
    try
    {
        responseMessage = await httpClient.PostAsync(adaptiveUri, content).ConfigureAwait(false);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        if (responseMessage == null)
            responseMessage = new HttpResponseMessage
            {
                StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError,
                ReasonPhrase = $"PostRequestAsync failed: {ex.Message}"
            };
    }
    return responseMessage;
}
```

My endpoint responds normally to our other software, so I'm pretty sure the endpoint is solid, I can't fathom why the post response is blocked, when the send isn't.

Comment: In your usage of `SendAsync`, you're not including content. In `PostAsync` you are including content. I'd argue that this is much more relevant to your question than which method you're using.

Comment: Good point - I changed the Send to included content, and it now has the same behavior. Now to figure out why it's timing out.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

`SendAsync` can make any http verb request depending on how you set that property. `PostAsync` and similar are just convenience methods. Those convenience methods use `SendAsync` internally which is why when you derive a handler you only need to override `SendAsync` and not all of the send methods.

**To your other question though:**
When you use `SendAsync` you need to create the content and pass it. Your only sending an empty message. The 500 likely means that the api got `null` from the model binding and kicked you back. Just as @John commented.

Comment: Fair enough really, I'm just unclear why one is blocking (Post / Timeout), and the other isn't (Send / Response immediately.)

Comment: I don't quite understand what behavior you're seeing, can you elaborate? And does the `TaskCancelledException` have an inner exception? [Feel free to browse the source here](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.Net.Http/src/System/Net/Http/HttpClient.cs)

Comment: Nope, no inner exception, and CancellationRequest= false, which is why I'm assuming a timeout.

Comment: @Ian Does the server send a big response to the request? Perhaps you need to look at HttpCompletionOptions and just wait for the headers at the point of POST.

Comment: Hi @JSteward does it hold true when we are working with .Net 6(core)? we have migrated our code from .Net framework 4.6 to .Net 6 and when we are making client.SendAsync(request).ConfigureAwait(false).
on hitting the api the value of request.Content is all becoming null.
is it like we have to drop NewtonSoft.Json and use System.Text.Json?